# What do hotel or restaurant employees call the place at the back where tables and chairs are arranged..?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

What do hotel or restaurant employees call the place at the back where tables and chairs are arranged..? It isn't a kitchen or a staff lounge but, it's a place for servers to prepare things needed while business hours such as folding napkins and cleaning glasses. And the place is not invisible for customers. Sometimes when workers feel tired, they take a rest for a few minutes there, usually standing.(There is usually not a big space.) In my country we just call it "Backside", I feel like it's wrong in real English. Is there any proper word for that place?

Comment: I know the word back office. especially for hotels.

Comment: Somehow I don't think *backside* would fit the bill. I'm trying to imagine a visit from the health and safety inspector who has to say *Could I see your backside please*!

Comment: @WS2 - LOL! Or imagine some thieves trying to break in... "Listen up folks, we're gonna come through the *backside*".. :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are generally referred to as  ***[service spaces](http://www.iadclexicon.org/service-spaces/)***:

> - Service spaces are those used for galleys, pantries containing cooking appliances, lockers and store-rooms, workshops other than those forming part of the machinery spaces, and similar spaces and trunks to such spaces.

(www.iadclexicon.org)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***wait station (area)***

> *The wait station is the area that holds supplies for your servers*.
> [The Everything Guide to Starting and Running a Restaurant](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PPdpzCga5coC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=%22wait+station%22&source=bl&ots=xuOOZF-b3r&sig=0ghla8YZWdisz2PHTioqWhw2fYs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL7amRs-_KAhULPRoKHVW8BakQ6AEIWDAQ#v=onepage&q=%22wait%20station%22&f=false)

[***sidestation (area)***](http://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187497-d947344-i78786695-Visual_Restaurant_Panoramic-Barcelona_Catalonia.html) might also fit the bill.

> *Bussers are typically expected to stock the sidestation and restock it as needed throughout the meal* [F&B: Bussers - Who Needs 'Em?](http://www.eatiquette.com/NACbussers.pdf)
>
> busser: *US* a person who removes dirty dishes and resets tables in a restaurant :  a restaurant worker who buses tables : *The classic service involves smoothly functioning teams of captains, waiters and bussers, who seem to know just how friendly to be without stepping over the line.* — Harvey Steiman, Wine Spectator, 15 Mar. 1995
>
> bus (*also*, bus cart): a four-wheeled cart for carrying dishes in a restaurant [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bus)